# Using .on() and targeting elements with a specific attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-selectors

I understand you can use `.on()` to attach a single click event to an element and then specify which child elements receive the click. So, for example:

```
$(this.el).on("click", "span", function () {
    alert("Bloop!");
});
```

I need to be a bit more specific and target selectors with a particular attribute, like this:

```
$(this.el).on("click", "span[data-placeholder]", function () {
    alert("Bloop!");
});
```

That doesn't seem to work, though. As soon as I add the attribute it stops working. No errors, just doesn't seem to find the elements.

Is that the expected behavior? Is there a way around it?

**CLARITY**

`$(this.el)` is just a div that contains a number of elements, some of which are `<span data-placeholder="First Name"></span>` tags. There could be dozens of those `<span>` tags and I didn't want that many event listeners, so I thought I'd use `.on()` to add the click to the parent container.

Comment: That should work, as long as the span has a `data-placeholder` attribute. Note that `.data()` doesn't create attributes.

Comment: Are you setting `placeholder` via data api? if so it won't create an attribute. Otherwise it should work.

Comment: can you show your actual code http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: What is `this.el`? If it is a span it will not work as your syntax is for delegation

Comment: @Starx Well, we know it is a parent of a span since the first snippet works.

Comment: Edited OP for clarity.

Comment: Your code works. http://jsfiddle.net/gJurd/

Comment: @KevinB — These spans are created in Backbone views, and these data attributes are apparently converted to `data()` and removed as attributes.

Comment: Would one of you like to post an answer stating that using the data() api won't work so I can accept it? That's the problem with my original code…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbuckley/ap4EB/) showing your example working, with both existing `<span>`s and with newly created ones.

Just to be clear, this will work with your event delegation:

```
var span = $('<span>Test</span>');
span.attr('data-placeholder', 'test'); // declare as an attribute
$(this.el).append(span);
span.click();
```

This will not:

```
var span = $('<span>Test</span>');
span.data('placeholder', 'test'); // declare with .data()
$(this.el).append(span);
span.click();
```

jQuery's [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method will read properties from data attributes if declared, but does not store them as attributes on the element when adding data.

Here's another [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbuckley/ZLQS8/).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("span[data-placeholder]", this.el).on("click", function () {
    alert("Bloop!");
});
```

Comment: That would attach the event handler separately on each element which is what OP was trying to avoid as far as I can tell.

Comment: @vp_arth for instance, if the `span`s within the element are deleted and recreated after creating the event handler. Read about [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to filter your spans

```
$('span', this.el).filter(function() {
     return $(this).hasAttr('data-placeholder');
}).on('click', function() {
   //This is for all the spans having data-placeholder
   //...
});
```

Or if the `placeholder` is set via data api:

```
$(this.el).filter(function() {
     return $(this).data('placeholder') != 'undefined';
}).on('click', function() {
   //This is for all the spans having data-placeholder
   //...
});
```

This functions above select those elements specifically, if event delegation on the OP is needed, then you can do the following:

```
$('span', this.el).on('click', 'span', function() {
     if($(this).data('placeholder') != 'undefined') {
         alert('bloop');
     }
});
```

Comment: Why do you think he doesn't want to use event delegation?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen, Because I thought that was not intended.

Comment: You must've missed the "Why" at the beginning of my sentence

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen, Oh.. due to this line `need to be a bit more specific and target selectors with a particular attribute`

Comment: @Starx that still doesn't suggest that he wouldn't want to use delegation.

Comment: @cbuckley, I think the latest update to the OP supports my assumption.

Comment: @Starx I think the opposite.

Comment: @KevinB, How so? And How about I put an event delegation version. Will that make you boys happy?

Comment: yes and no, since an event delegation version would literally be what he already has, which is already working. the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @Starx if the attribute is added in JS after the events are bound, then the above code wouldn't pick up those new spans.

Comment: @Starx: I thought that point was obvious, since that's one of the main reasons event delegation exists in the first place - to catch events from elements added/modified after the fact.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen, What is your idea of trying to tell me about why event delegation exists? I read OP is trying to select specific elements not delegation, why are you favoring event delegation? It has its place of correct use. Just because it works, does not mean it is right in every little scenario. I am tried of you people trying to force teach me that OP is asking about event delegation and it should be event delegation. delegation, delegation, delegation. It was not obvious to me alright? I tried to find clear statements in question and used what I got and it was selection not delegation.

Answer (score -2):

add a id to your span and pin point it using # tag